# CSS unsorted list with many submenus

Tags: html, css

I wrote a CSS unsorted menu and it did show up the correct first name and the submenu.

Whenever I hover [Helpdesk System] > [New Task] which was no problem to display.

Whenever I hover [Helpdesk System] > [Task Overview] there was a problem. it shown [Hardware Inventory] > [New Hardware].

What I guess is [New Task>Task Overview] and [Hardware Inventory>New Hardware] were hidden and overlapped.

How can I correct this ?

[image: Capture 1]

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="topbanner">

<ul class="rightmenu">
    <li><a href="<? echo ROOT_NAME ?>/home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Helpdesk System</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Task</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tasks Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search Tasks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hardware Inventory</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Hardware</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search Hardware</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">No FME Assets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Misplace Assets</a></li>                        
            <li><a href="#">Hardware Tracking</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<? echo ROOT_NAME; ?>/webspace/">Web Space</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Application System</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vendor Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Administration</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Staff Administration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Department Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Actions Tracking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login History</a></li>      
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logoff</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#topbanner    { 
width:100%; height:25px; margin:0;position:relative;background-color:#4c4e5a;display: block;}

.rightmenu, .rightmenu ul, .rightmenu li, .rightmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; outline: none; }

.rightmenu { float: right; }    
.rightmenu li a{
display: block; padding: 0 14px; margin: 3px 0;color: #f3f3f3;background-color: #4c4e5a;}

.rightmenu ul {
    position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
background-color: #4c4e5a;
left: auto;
right:0;
width:180px;
}

.rightmenu ul ul {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
right: 100%;
top: 0%;
background-color: #4c4e5a;
width:180px;
}

.rightmenu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; } 
.rightmenu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; } 

.rightmenu ul li{
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding: 0; 
}

.rightmenu li:hover > ul li {  
height: 25px;
overflow: visible; 
padding:0;
} 

.rightmenu ul li a { 
white-space: nowrap;
border: none;
}
```

I have omitted some styling in order to make the code short for you. (like shadow, border style, and round corner)

Comment: html would be helpful too

Comment: here fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cjwd/
...you can add this to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that you're using "opacity:0" when you should be using "display:none." The opacity property only sets an elements alpha level, but display sets how an element interacts with the other elements on the page.

Your main issue however is that you've generalized your CSS to much. Normally generalizing code is a great habit to get into, but in this case you need to be a little more specific with what level of navigation the user is pointing at.

Here is the bit of code that you should focus on:

```
.rightmenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #4c4e5a;
    left: auto;
    right:0;
    width:180px;
    top: 25px;
}

.rightmenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    background-color: #4c4e5a;
    width:180px;
}
.rightmenu ul ul:hover, .rightmenu li li:hover > ul { 
    right: 100%; 
    display: block;
}

.rightmenu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; } 
.rightmenu li:hover > ul, .rightmenu li > ul:hover { display: block; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/fvy8b/)